# I cannot call getColor method using ContextCompat object. It wont let me pass getContext() as its first parameter

Tags: android

So this is what I am doing.The below statement is the last line of an int `return type` method.

```
return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),magColor);
```

The error says that i have passed the wrong first argument.
Precisely:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.security.AccessControlContext',
>   required: 'android.content.Context'

Entire Method:

```
public int getMagnitudeColor(double mag) {
  int magColor;
  int mag1=(int) mag;
  switch (mag1) {
    case 1:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude1;
      break;
    case 2:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude2;
      break;
    case 3:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude3;
      break;
    case 4:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude4;
      ;
      break;
    case 5:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude5;
      break;
    case 6:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude6;
      break;
    case 7:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude7;
      break;
    case 8:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude8;
      break;
    case 9:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude9;
      break;
    default:
      magColor = R.color.magnitude10plus;
      break;
  }
  return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),magColor);
}
```

Comment: post the entire method!

Comment: from where are you calling `getMagnitudeColor`?

Comment: @ Gurupad Mamadapur His method of retrieving the Color is perfectly valid and is actually preferable over the legacy way you describe. Hist problem is that getContext() is not returning the type of context he needs but that is due to the class he is calling it from.

Comment: @Kuffs Yea that was my bad.

Comment: calling getMagnitudeColor in  my custom adapter class

Comment: Please post the custom Adapter which relevant to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `getContext()` in:

```
return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),magColor);
```

is not `android.content.Context`.

You need to use context from `Activity`, `Service`, `Application` and `View`.

If you use custom class, you need to pass the context to the class.

Comment: how? Can you please give me the solution?

Comment: if you have a view in your custom adapter, you can get the context from it by using `View.getContext()`. Then pass it to your method. But first change the method to accept context parameter like `public int getMagnitudeColor(Context context, double mag)` and use it `return ContextCompat.getColor(context,magColor);`

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked , 1 single line

```
view.listViewPalabrasLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context,color))
```

where "listViewPalabrasLinearLayout" is the id of my layout and "color" is the variable I specify the color